# java treeviewer add element

Tags: java, treeview, jface, treeviewer

basically I am working with a treeviewer in Java (org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer).
Now my problem is, that I want to add an childelement/ item to an existing knot.

First of all my tree looks like this:

```
Knot A
Knot B
Knot C
 >child1
 >child2
```

These children(child1, child2) arent added manually, they are generated before I get my hands on the tree itself.

1. I create the treeviewer: 
   `viewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
   | SWT.V_SCROLL);`
2. I populate the treeviewer: 
   `viewer.setInput(....elements());`
   which generates the state from above.
3. `viewer.getTree().getItem(0)` returns the correct knot A of my tree.

But I cant add a new child to an existing knot.
I tried the following and other things:

`TreeItem newItem = new TreeItem(items[0], SWT.NONE); and
    viewer.add(items[0], newItem); with a newly created item
    viewer.refresh();`

Theoretically I could manipulate the arrayList which populates the treeviewer in the first place but that would be really bad I think.

I really do not know what I am doing wrong right now.
I guess it is a quite silly question. If that is the case, then I am sorry.^^

Thank you for your help, I am grateful for every hint that you can offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating your 'model' (the data you give to `setInput`) is the correct way to update the tree. Call `TreeViewer.refresh()` or `TreeViewer.refresh(element)` to get the tree viewer to update the tree from the model.

When you are using `TreeViewer` you **never** create `TreeItem` objects - the viewer does that. Everything you pass to the `refresh`, `update`, `add` ... methods are objects from your model not TreeItems.